# X264--Why does "--pass 1 --stats" make the file bigger?

Tags: video, encoding, compression, x264

I am using `--pass 1 --stats <stats file location>` to generate the stats file for H.264 encoding with x264. The command is like this:

```
<x264 binary> <input file> -o <output file> --preset veryslow --crf 27 
  --tune ssim  --scenecut 0 --pass 1 --stats <stats file location>
```

When I ran this command with and without `--pass 1 --stats <stats file location>`, the difference between the sizes of the final output files are very different. The one with `--pass 1 --stats <stats file location>` is much bigger. What is the reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `--pass N` options when you do 2 pass encoding. Doing 2 pass encoding allow x264 to reach an exact bitrate you would specified. The first pass will generate a stats file that will be used at the second pass encoding. Onc second pass is done, you could remove the stats file.

So when you run just the `--pass 1` command without the `--pass 2` command it's like you didn't finish the job!

If it's still unclear to you I suggest you read that short documentation on [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) concerning the pass.

If you want in a file what is printed out in the console during the x264 encoding process, read [How to get output of X264?](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-114664.html)

Answer (score 1):

`--pass 1` without `--slow-firstpass` option (except `--preset placebo` where it is enabled by default) force use of faster settings which have lower compression ratio and so it change file size (usually making it bigger at the same crf).